# Probability of independent transmission attempts (independent Bernoulli trials)

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, discrete-distributions

I am trying to figure out the independent transmission attempts (independent Bernoulli trials)  probability $q$ for a sender node to remain in the same (waiting) state if receiving node is in sleep state, and probability $p$ for sender node to exit the waiting state if the receiving node is in active state. Therefore, the probability mass function of the random variable $P(D_{h})$ is given below, where a sender node that remains in a waiting-time state for a consecutive $\mathfrak{M}_{k}$ number of times is forced to drop the packet.

$$P(D_{h_{i}}) = \displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}\binom{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}q^{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}p^{0}= q^{\mathfrak{M}_{k}} \quad\quad\quad (1)$$

Also on the other hand I have doubt that this equation should be written in correct form that is given below

$$P(D_{h_{i}}) = \displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}\binom{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}q^{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}p^{0}= {\mathfrak{M}_{k}} \times q\quad\quad\quad (2)$$

because that $\mathfrak{M}_{k}$ on the left side of Eq. (2) comes from summation sign.

In Eq. (1) the $q^{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}$  should be $q$ because each time there is a transmission attempt then $\mathfrak{M}_{k}$ will be count as one attempt, hence, $q^{1}$ remains $q$ and $\mathfrak{M}_{k}$ from the summation is the number of times attempts occur will multiply the probability of node in sleep state $q$ which equals $\mathfrak{M}_{k} \times q$ on the left side of equation.

Kindly guide me which equation is correct, am I right in Eq. (2) or not?
Did I misunderstand some key points in the problem?

Regards.

Comment: I am not sure why you are using Fraktur but in any case is $\binom{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}=1$?  Or should it be $\binom{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}{{k}}$?

Comment: @Henry thank you for your response, and yes in any case $\binom{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}{\mathfrak{M}_{k}}=1$.